# Float Left Suppressing CSS Accordion

Tags: css, navigation, accordion

I have a CSS accordion menu which works 100% correctly. However I want to float the div left and when I add Float:Left to the CSS, the accordion stops working. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I tried adding Clear:both to #menu_box but no success.

CSS:

```
#menu_box {
    float: left;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li a {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #337D88;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.menu > li:first-child a {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #4AADBB;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.menu li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li li a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 0;
  background: #C6DDD9;
  color: #1F3D39;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.menu > li:hover li a {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.menu > li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #A4CAC8;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu_box" style="clear:both;">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li> <a href="#">General</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="settings.php">Update Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="changepassword.php">Change Password</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Logs</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="easyjet.php">EasyJet Booking Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="invoices.php">Invoice Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricematch.php">Price Match Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="tid.php">TID Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="transavia.php">Transavia Booking Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="villas.php">Villa Booking Log</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1n6vtrq/).

Comment: create a demo be better?

Comment: please provide your html as well ! ;)

Comment: HTML now included - thanks for taking a look

Comment: Just created the demo (in edited question). As you can see, it works fine in the demo...

Comment: _"As you can see, it works fine in the demo"_ It's hard to fix a problem we can't see

Comment: A good point - which in turn led me to research the effects of other div positions on the page. After adjusting the position of one of the divs from fixed to inherit, the accordion now works as intended (and as shown in the fiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set "width: auto;" to parent "" .menu    i.e.,                               .menu {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: auto;}                                                                  2. Add separate class for parent li  i.e,  General and  Logs                         .parent{float: left;
   display: inline-block;}